# Getting join results using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new to LINQ. I'm trying to join two tables, but I have difficulties returning the results.

Here is my code:

```
 using (DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext())
     {
         var list = db.Products.Join(db.ProductDetails,
         p => p.ID,
         d => d.ProductID,
         (p, d) => new {
         p.ID,p.Photo,d.Name,d.LanguageID
         }).Where(d=>d.LanguageID== lang).ToList();
    }
```

Well I can not use the variable `list` outside using and when I declare the variable outside 'using' (before it) like: `var list;`.

I get the error:

> Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized

**Update:**

I changed the code to:

```
DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();

                        var products = db.Products.Join(db.ProductDetails,
                           p => p.ID,
                           d => d.ProductID,
                           (p, d) => new {
                              p.ID,p.Photo,d.Name,d.LanguageID
                           }).Where(d=>d.LanguageID== langs[language].ParseInt()).ToList();
```

and it worked. As I have omitted `using`, do I have to do anything like closing the connection?

Is there a problem not using the `using`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use the results of the query in the same scope, you must make it typed so you can declare variables of appropriate type.  First define a class for the result objects and use it.  It would be cleaner to put this all as a method.

```
public class Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
}
```

```
public List<Result> GetJoinResult(int languageId)
{
    using (DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext())
    {
        return db.Products.Join(db.ProductDetails, p => p.ID, d => d.ProductID,
            (p, d) => new Result // not anonymous
            {
                ID = p.ID,
                Photo = p.Photo,
                Name = d.Name,
                LanguageID = d.LanguageID,
            })
            .Where(x => x.LanguageID == languageId)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

---

If defining the types is too much, then you *must* use it immediately in the same scope.

```
using (DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext())
{
    var results = db.Products.Join(db.ProductDetails, p => p.ID, d => d.ProductID,
        (p, d) => new
        {
            p.ID,
            p.Photo,
            d.Name,
            d.LanguageID,
        })
        .Where(x => x.LanguageID == languageId)
        .ToList();
    // do stuff with results
}
```

Comment: I know it but for many many results that I will get from different joins I don't want to create structs or classes for each of them (because of the curiosity and laziness) I want to know how can I get the results its not important to use `using` any way that it i possible

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani You cannot return an anonymous type from a method. In the case you are after you will have to do all your logic inside the method. It is better to create all the models.

Comment: I added an Update to my question, would you please have a look at it and say your opinion?

Comment: That's good and fine, you'll probably want to dispose the context eventually.  Off the top of my head, I don't recall if it will be catastrophic if you forget to.  Connections are used as they are needed IIRC, but the context is tracking entities and other housekeeping and may use up a fair bit of memory which you may want to recover quickly.